# Is there any solution to transfer data to any stream in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, c++14, ostream

### Summary

I'm implementing a Data Structure from scratch without using templates by the moment, all I have is a simple prototype of a **Vector**.

Part of the operations of that DS is a method called `print` and I want to pass any possible stream, so I used the technique of adding a `std::ostream&` parameter. In that way I could use the global `std::cout` or any other ouput stream like a `stringstream`. So, testing that operation with unit test is going to be easier, because I could use a `stringstream` instead.

All is implemented and the compilation is successful, but I don't know exactly why the console output when using a `std::cout` stream is giving me weird characters, for example an output like `, ⌂≈⌂┘≈⌂.┘≈⌂┴.┘≈⌂☺70`. I thought it was because the `print` operation was looping out of the scope reading junk, but after debugging it seems to be everything okay.

### Implementations

First of all, here is the code of the `print` operation.

```
void Vector::print(std::ostream& stream)
{
    auto index = 0;

    while (index < this -> size) {
        auto value = this->get(index);

        if (index < (this->size - 1))
            stream << value + ", ";
        else
            stream << value;

        index++;
    }
}
```

And the in the file of `main.cpp` I have these lines below.

```
using std::cout; 
using std::cin; 
using std::endl;
using std::getline; 


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Vector numbers(11);

    auto index = 0;
    unsigned long v_size = numbers.getSize(); 

    while (index < v_size) {
        numbers.set(index, (index * 7));
        index++;
    }

    numbers.print();

    return 0;
}
```

## Update here:

Update, thankfully someone gave me a link related to a question that seems to solve the problem. Thank you so much anonymous user. Below is my new implementation

### New Implementations

The code of the `print` operation.

```
void Vector::print(std::ostream& stream, bool format_inline)
{
    auto index = 0;

    while (index < this -> size) {
        auto value = this->get(index);
        
        stringstream ss; 

        if (format_inline)
            ss << this->format_text_inline(value, index);
        else
            ss << this->format_text(value);

        stream << ss.str(); 

        index++;
    }
}
```

Then I also added two separated methods just to split more my code.

```
string Vector::format_text_inline(int value, int index)
{
    stringstream ss;

    if (index < (this->size - 1))
        ss << value << ", ";
    else
        ss << value;

    return ss.str();
}

string Vector::format_text(int value)
{
    stringstream ss; 

    ss << value << "\n";

    return ss.str(); 
}
```

These methods are private. Maybe in the future may be good to grab this and create a new class just to format text.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: That “Important Note” is wrong. It’s quite common for a data structure to have a `print` function. It makes it easy to implement a stream inserter.

Comment: Update, thankfully someone gave me a link related to a question that seems to solve the problem. Thank you so much anonymous user. 

In the same question I'll be setting up my new implementation.

Comment: @PeteBecker understood the logic there, thank you.